# Замена слова и переход на новую строку Java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть какой-то текст в формате `String`, нужно после каждой 5 точки поставить переход на новую строку (`\n`) и заменить слово "Today" на "Tomorrow".

Помогите с реализацией regexp, но буду рад, если можно как-то по другому.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Заменить `Today` на `Tomorrow` можно элементарно при помощи метода `String.replaceAll`. Это настолько очевидно, что даже не стоит упоминания. А вот регулярка для первой части задания более интересна. Например, можно сделать так:

```
s.replaceAll("((.*?\\.){5})", "$1\n");
```

Недостаток в том, что это решение будет учитывать точки и внутри слова (например, оно может разорвать сокращение `т.е.`). Поэтому воспользуемся тем, что в большинстве языков после точки в конце предложения ставится пробел:

```
s.replaceAll("((.*?\\.\\s+){5})", "$1\n");
```

Побочным эффектом второго решения является то, что оно уберёт пробелы в начале перенесённых строк, чем страдает первое решение. Теперь пробелы  остаются в конце строк. Убрать их будет посложнее, но возможно:

```
s.replaceAll("((.*?\\.\\s+){4}(.*?\\.))\\s+", "$1\n");
```